# Wordpress how to load a custom theme through my plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, themes, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using a `shortcode` to output content but I don't want to be surrounded by anything else.

How to avoid loading the wordpress theme?

How can I load a custom theme through my plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way that I have found is using the `template_redirect` hook:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'myoutput');
function myoutput()
{
    if ('my code to decide if output without load a theme')
    {
        include ('/myoutput.php'); // file must be properly html coded
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's better for you to use custom fields, so in your single or page file you should check like "if has X single field, echo just content, else, call wp_head and all this stuff"

Comment: Your solution seems to be applied in a theme file, right? I need to code it into a plugin. Thanks.-